# Replace words in a string without using replace in Java

Tags: java, string

I am trying to replace all occurrences of a word in a string. However with this code I can only find the first occurrence of it and replace it. Is there any way to expand this code to replace the words in the entire string? I am attempting to do this without using the replace built in methods in Java since I already know how to use those function, I was wondering if there was another way to go about it.

```
public static String replace(String old, String newWord, String input) {    

int i = input.indexOf(old);

if (i < 0) {
    return input;
}

    String partBefore = input.substring(0, i);
    String partAfter  = input.substring(i + old.length());

    return partBefore + newWord + partAfter;
}
```

Comment: `new` is a reserved keyword in Java

Comment: Use [`indexOf(String str, int fromIndex)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(java.lang.String,%20int))

Comment: Always use Regular expression, but you should again use **replaceAll"

Comment: @zigmaempire it's not advisable to immediately resort to regex for such a simple search/replace

Comment: You are referring to an undefined variable `line` in `return line;`. I assume that you mean `return input;`

Comment: Yes, sorry about that

Answer (score 1):

First, you need a loop of some kind. Probably a `while`.

In the loop, since you're replacing the "old" string, you could just keep looping until you don't find it anymore. But if you want to avoid re-searching the first part of the string, or if you want to allow the replacement to contain the string it's replacing (without then looping infinitely), then once you've done each replacement, use [`String#indexOf(String str, int fromIndex)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf-java.lang.String-int-), which lets you continue from the middle of the string.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static String replace(String old, String newWord, String input) {    
    int i = input.indexOf(old);
    if (i < 0) {
        return input;
    }
    String partBefore = input.substring(0, i);
    String partAfter  = input.substring(i + old.length());
    return partBefore + newWord + replace(old, newWord, partAfter );
}
```

However, it's more efficient to collect the bits and pieces in a StringBuilder.

```
public static String replace(String oldStr, String newStr, String input) {    
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int i;
    int prev = 0;
    while( (i = input.indexOf(oldStr, prev)) >= 0 ){
        sb.append( input.substring(prev, i) ).append( newStr );
        prev = i + oldStr.length();
    }
    sb.append(input.substring(prev));
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: @Bohemian It's possible to use recursion.

Comment: I guess we came up with the same idea :)

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Just trying to demonstrate that recursion is possible without too much effort. In terms of efficiency, using a StringBuilder to collect the unmodified and replaced pieces is preferable.

Comment: If you want to be optimal, you first find out how many times the pattern occurs, then when you construct the StringBuilder you can do `new StringBuilder(input.length() + count * (newStr.length() - oldStr.length()))` :-). But I think recursion does pretty well in terms of understandability, which is also important.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Good point, but if we're about to split hairs: if the new string is shorter than the old string you can forget the extra pass to count the occurrencies - just use the input's length for the StringBuilder. And if it is longer, divide input's length by oldStr's length and multiply by newStr's length to obtain a worst case length for the StringBuilder constructor. This should also be faster than an extra pass unless it beats the maximum string builder length or your memory ;-)

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple solution that uses recursion. Once you have replaced the word for the first time in the string, you can then replace the word in the `partAfter` part of the string by calling the replace method again:

```
public static String replace(String old, String newWord, String input) {    

    int i = input.indexOf(old);

    if (i < 0) {
        return input;
    }

    String partBefore = input.substring(0, i);
    String partAfter  = input.substring(i + old.length());

    return partBefore + newWord + 
           replace(old, newWord, partAfter); // <<-- Note recursion here 
}
```

This only changes one line from your original source.

Comment: This one works perfect, except what if the word is within another word like if you wanted to remove the word 'move' from 'remove' for example?

Comment: That just works; you can try it: `replace("move", "", "remove")`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't use `new` for a variable name. It's a reserved word.

Second of all, in order to replace multiple occurences, you should have a loop.

Finally, it's better to create the new String using a StringBuilder, not String concatenation.

This is untested, but something like this should work:

```
public static String replace(String oldStr, String newStr, String input) {    

    int i = input.indexOf(oldStr);
    if (i < 0) {
        return input;
    }
    StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
    int prev = 0;
    while (i >= 0) {   
        String partBefore = input.substring(prev, i);
        prev = i + oldStr.length();
        buffer.append(partBefore);
        buffer.append(newStr);    
        i = input.indexOf(oldStr, i + oldStr.length());
    }
    buffer.append(input.substring(i+oldStr.length()));

    return buffer.toString();
}
```

Comment: This code compiles and everything, however, once running a test case is simply adds the word right in front of the one I want to remove, but doesn't actually remove the word

Comment: @LBS_Me Oh, I see where I was wrong. Change `prev = i;` to `prev = i + oldStr.length();`.

Answer (score 0):

**Use Recursion:**

```
public static String replaceAll(String old, String newWord, String input) {

    int i = input.indexOf(old);

    if (i < 0)
        return input;

    String partBefore = input.substring(0, i);
    String partAfter = input.substring(i + old.length());

    return replaceAll(old, newWord, partBefore + newWord + partAfter);
}
```

**Use do-While and go on replacing words:**

```
public static String replaceAll(String old, String newWord, String input) {

    boolean loop = true;

    do {
        int i = input.indexOf(old);

        if (i > 0) {

            String partBefore = input.substring(0, i);
            String partAfter = input.substring(i + old.length());
            input = partBefore + newWord + partAfter;

        } else
            loop = false;

    } while (loop);

    return input;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Code

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class replacechar {
       String line;
       String s = "";
       char from ;
       char to ;
       public replacechar()
       {
           Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
           System.out.println("Enter The String");
           line = scan.nextLine();
           System.out.println("Enter The Character you want to changer");
           from = scan.nextLine().charAt(0);
           System.out.println("Enter the Character you want to replace with");
           to = scan.nextLine().charAt(0);
           replacecharacter(from,to);
       }
       public void replacecharacter(char f,char t)
       {
           for(int i =0;i< line.length();i++)
           {

               if(line.charAt(i) == f)
               {
                  s += t;
               }
               else
               {
                   s += line.charAt(i);
               }

           }
           System.out.println(s);
       }
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        replacechar  obj = new replacechar();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure if OP is still looking for answers but it might help others. Here is my code with just for loop and java's substring method...

```
public static void main(String ar[])
{

 String str = "This is some string. replace lower case is with IS";
        String pattern = "is";
        String replaceWith = "IS"; // word to replace with
        System.out.println(replaceString(str, pattern, replaceWith));

    }

    static String replaceString(String str, String pattern, String replaceWith) {
        String temp = "";
        String replacedString = ""; // Replaced String
        int remainingString = 0; // append the rest of the string after last
                                    // occurance of pattern.
        for (int i = 0; i <= str.length() - pattern.length(); i++) {
            temp = str.substring(i, i + 1);

            if (str.substring(i, i + pattern.length()).equals(pattern)) {
                temp = replaceWith + " ";
                i += pattern.length();

            }
            remainingString = i;
            replacedString += temp;

        }
        replacedString += str.substring(remainingString + 1, str.length());

        return replacedString;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Posting this here incase somebody needs an implementation without using StringUtils helper methods.

```
     static String replaceAll(String str, String oldW, String newW) {
            // code here
            char[] ch = str.toCharArray();
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < ch.length;i++) {
                if (ch[i] == oldW.charAt(0) && checkForString(i+1,oldW,str)) {
                 sb.append(newW);
                 i += oldW.length() -1;
                }
                else
                    sb.append(ch[i]);
            }
            
            return sb.toString();
        }
        
        static boolean checkForString(int i, String str,String ogStr) {
            int start = i;
            for (int j = 1; j < str.length() && i < ogStr.length(); j++, i++) {
                if (ogStr.charAt(i) != str.charAt(j))
                    return false;
            }
            return (i-start+1) == str.length()?true:false;
        }
```